# java web: how to redirect stacktrace of uncaught exception to a log file?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I want to redirect only stacktrace of uncaught exception from console to log file. The rest of the things should appear on console as usual.

Comment: May be I can redirect System.err to a log file at the start up. I gueess by default printstacktrace. Probably using  System.setErr

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Set](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setUncaughtExceptionHandler(java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler)) a [`Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29) that prints to the desired file. `printStackTrace` is threadsafe, so several threads may share the same `PrintStream`.

Comment: Gustafc, i never heard this thing, But yes it works like charm :)

Answer (score 4):

Created a sample program for this, Thanx to ***gustafc***

```
public class UncaughtException {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler( new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler(){
            public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
                System.out.println("*****Yeah, Caught the Exception*****");
                e.printStackTrace(); // you can use e.printStackTrace ( printstream ps )
            }
        });     

        System.out.println( 2/0 );  // Throw the Exception 
    }
}
```

**Output is**

> *****Yeah, Caught the Exception***** java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by
>   zero  at
>   thread.UncaughtException.main(UncaughtException.java:12)